# How do I get Shiro's annotations to work in Grails?

Tags: grails, shiro

I'm trying to apply annotation-based security to my Grails app.

Peter says [here](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/grails-plugin-annotations-td1493905.html) that we should be using Shiro's annotations instead of the quasi-deprecated grails-shiro plugin annotations.

How does one get that working?

I'm finding the grails-shiro plugin strays from how Shiro does things, what with the Realm-converting and all. Has anyone tried implementing Shiro directly rather than using the grails plugin? Any success?

Thanks,
Graham.

Comment: So, it appears that they do work out of the box, so long as you have annotations enabled in your `Config.groovy`. That said, they do not appear to work on methods in a Controller, including actions (when declared as methods ala Grails 2.0+ and not as closures). Still investigating...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G'day I have taken over the Grails-Shiro plugin project. I'm currently re-writing the functional tests and can confirm that the shiro annotations do work, with a couple of caveats:

- You can use them in controllers on method actions in grails 2.x
- You can use them on Service methods
- They don't currently work on service *classes* (I'm investigating this)

e.g. this works on a service

```
class SecuredMethodsService {

def methodOne() {
    return 'one'
}

@RequiresGuest
def methodTwo() {
    return 'two'
}

@RequiresUser
def methodThree() {
    return 'three'
}

@RequiresAuthentication
def methodFour() {
    return 'four'
}

@RequiresRoles('User')
def methodFive() {
    return 'five'
}

@RequiresPermissions("book:view")
def methodSix() {
    return 'six'
}
```

}

or in a controller on an action method like this:

```
    @RequiresAuthentication
def unrestricted() {
    render(view: 'simple', model: [msg: "secure action"])
}
```

When using annotations you may need to add an "afterView" filter to catch the AuthorizationException thrown by the annotation e.g.

```
class ShiroSecurityFilters {
def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
        before = {
            // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
            if (!controllerName) return true
            // Access control by convention.
            accessControl()
        }
        afterView = { e ->
            while (e && !(e instanceof AuthorizationException)) {
                e = e.cause
            }

            if (e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
                if (e instanceof UnauthenticatedException) {
                    // User is not authenticated, so redirect to the login page.
                    flash.message = "You need to be logged in to continue."
                    redirect(
                            controller: 'auth',
                            action: 'login',
                            params: [targetUri: request.forwardURI - request.contextPath])
                } else {
                    redirect(controller: 'auth', action: 'unauthorized')
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

I hope that helps. A new version of the plugin should be released RSN.

Cheers,
Peter.

Comment: Does it need any extra configuration, or it should be enabled by default, and gets going as soon as i put an annotation on a controller action method

Comment: Looks like the old annotations related code (processController and processAnnotations) in ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy is dead and of no use any more, I dont see controllerClass.roleMap or PermissionMap being used any where. 

Does shiro plugin still support the custom annotations, RoleRequired and PermissionRequired, and accessControl builder inside controller ! Looks like that code is lying around useless !

Comment: That code is deprecated, which means people use it and it works, so it's not useless. It will probably be removed in the future.

Comment: Isnt that code dead processController/processAnnotations in ShiroGrailsPlugin.groovy, is controllerClass.roleMap or PermissionMap being used any where !! I might be missing some thing though.

Comment: Use the standard annotations. Just look at the new tests here for examples https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/tree/master/test/projects/annotation-test/test/functional

add this to the config... and no you don't need role map or permission map, it's all done in the filter.
security {
    shiro {
        authc.required = false
        annotationdriven.enabled = true
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is anwering...

I don't know how you get the annotations to work, but I've used shiro in several Grails projects and didn't miss them... So why do you need them?

When you need to permission explicit roles, you can just create some `ShiroRole`s and assign star-permissions to them: 'book:*' allows a role to execute all actions on the book controller. 'book:list,show' allows a role to only list or show books.

When you need implicit permissions, use a filter. So if you want to give someone access if she is (for instance) the boss of someone, just fetch the object on which you want to decide in a filter and make a decision.

When you need switches in you gsp-code (e.g. show this only if it's an admin), use the shiro tags. Just unzip the shiro plugin and look for the taglibrary. It is well documented.

HTH

Comment: That's great if you're using the Shiro plugin's "security by convention" — ie: `controller:action` — but doesn't deal with securing resources anywhere _else_ than in this paradigm.

What about securing Services, Utils, or anything else. That's AOP/Annotations' sweet spot, and doesn't appear to be dealt with by the Shiro plugin.

Comment: I think this is beacuse grails is not intended to build up "internal" security. You access a service by accessing a controller:action - and this is what the plugin secures - it secures your grails app from the outside...

Comment: Hmm, I think I've gotten Shiro's native annotations to work for non-controller methods. Is there a reason why they won't work on controller methods?

Comment: Ralf, for anything other than the most basic web apps the Shiro plugin's "security by convention" is inadequate. If it doesn't support at least _most_ of the features Shiro provides, it shouldn't claim to be a "Shiro plugin". That said, I think I've narrowed the annotations' incompatibility to methods within controllers; they are working in services and elsewhere. It appears that the incompatibility only exists on controllers.

Comment: So, will you answer your question yourself, so that I can see what you mean?